# Qt interface based on panels

Tags: c++, qt, interface

I want to build interface which looks like this:[image]

There are panels `QDockPanel` to the sides. The main question is how to make main viewport (which is dark in the screen). When I resize, for example, right panel, it also changes the size. Could I use `QDockPanel` with layouts to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [QMainWindow](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qmainwindow.html#details). It does exactly that. The "main viewport" is called a central widget in the QMainWindow.

Comment: I've tried that but `centralWidget` geometry isn't that black area but the full one of the window size.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your program. Have you checked the Qt demos, I guess there are some good examples of QMainWindow usage with dock widgets.